# AWS Glue Job error: An error occurred while calling o82.parquet. Not Found

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, parquet, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

We use AWS Glue Jobs for some of our data processing. We use pyspark to process the data, but from time to time we see this error on some step of a job:

`An error occurred while calling o82.parquet. Not Found (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not Found; Request ID: ABC111; S3 Extended Request ID: ABC111abc111)`

This error seems to be intermittent and sometimes just rerunning the same job with same parameters seems to run fine, but it is definitely not a very descriptive error and we'd like to avoid it as our number of automated jobs grows.

In the Cloudwatch logs the latest logs I see:

```
WARN  [Executor task launch worker for task 1318] client.YarnClient (YarnClient.java:makeRestApiRequest(66)) - The GET request failed for the URL http://0.0.0.0:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps/application_1583197528647_0001
om.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 0.0.0.0:8088 [/0.0.0.0] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
...
ERROR [SIGTERM handler] executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend (SignalUtils.scala:apply$mcZ$sp(43)) - RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
```

The overview of the job:
reading json files using Glue Data Catalog, writes aggregated data into s3 in parquet format (I see a new partition here, but pretty sure it fails at this step as I don't see any messages that I put into the code after this); reads the data from the last step, reads csv mapping file from s3, joins 2 datasets, doing some additional calculations using pyspark, finally writes output to s3 in csv format.

Comment: Did you resolve this error?

Comment: Hi did you resolve this error? or did you find why this is happening?